# Beautifulsoup not exactly working. How can I solve?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

everyone. I try to do web scraping with python but I need help. It always gives the same results. How can I solve this? Thank you for now.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.findaphd.com/phds/cross-subject/?30gcApE600')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text, 'html.parser')
phd_pos = soup.find('div', class_='col-sm-19 col-sm-pull-5 col-xs-24 tight-left tight-xs course-content-info')

for phd in phd_pos:
    title = phd_pos.find('a', class_='courseLink phd-result__title').text
    uni_name=phd_pos.find('a', class_='instLink phd-result__dept-inst--inst phd-result__dept-inst--title').text.strip()
    dep_name=phd_pos.find('a', class_='deptLink phd-result__dept-inst--dept phd-result__dept-inst--title').text
    last_dat=phd_pos.find('a', class_='hoverTitle subButton grey').text


    print(f'''
    Position Title: {title}
    University name and Dep.: {uni_name}{','} {dep_name}
    Last Day: {last_dat}
    ''')
```

Comment: What are the errors? Expected output? What happened instead?

Comment: In extension to my previous comment - SO is not a code writing service. We are willing to help you understand, but we will not write code for you. Check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just guessing but perhaps you need `phd_pos = soup.find_all(...)` instead of just `soup.find(...)` then within your for loop, replace all calls to `phd_pos.find(...)` with `phd.find(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

See below. You were not using the variable `phd`. In addition, I used `.select(...)`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get(
    'https://www.findaphd.com/phds/cross-subject/?30gcApE600')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text, 'html.parser')
phd_pos = soup.select(
    'div.col-sm-19.col-sm-pull-5.col-xs-24.tight-left.tight-xs.course-content-info'
)

for phd in phd_pos:
    title = phd.find('a', class_='courseLink phd-result__title').text
    uni_name = phd.find(
        'a',
        class_=
        'instLink phd-result__dept-inst--inst phd-result__dept-inst--title'
    ).text.strip()
    dep_name = phd.find(
        'a',
        class_=
        'deptLink phd-result__dept-inst--dept phd-result__dept-inst--title'
    ).text
    last_dat = phd.find('a', class_='hoverTitle subButton grey').text

    print(f'''
    Position Title: {title}
    University name and Dep.: {uni_name}{','} {dep_name}
    Last Day: {last_dat}
    ''')
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I got it. But When I used "find_all" it's also okay. My mistake was used phd_pos variable in for loop.

Comment: That's what I said in the second part of my comment or did you not read that far? BTW, .select is more flexible in that it does not rely on the order of classes.